# Server composer install --no-dev killed

Tags: linux, laravel, web-services, composer-php, laravel-5.3

In server when I try update packages

```
composer install --no-dev
```

Result is

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `composer install` is trying to update packages, so you probably does not have `composer.lock` file in your project. In that case `composer install` works like `composer update` which requires a lot of memory. Your server probably does not have enough memory and process gets killed by OS.

The easiest way of solving this would be to generate `composer.lock` on dev environment, commit it into project, and then run `composer install` on server on project with `composer.lock`. Installing dependencies from `composer.lock` is cheap, so there should not be any memory-related problems.

If you can't do this, you need to more memory on your server - either enable swap or buy server with more RAM.

Comment: You are right there are missing `composer.lock` file. Thanks