# How to install Laravel on AWS free tier?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, composer-php

I am struggling to install Laravel on the AWS free tier Ubuntu instance. It gets stucks on the Composer installation due to a memory limit.

I initially ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-gd php7.2-mysql php7.2-curl php7.2-intl php7.2-mbstring php7.2-bcmath php7.2-imap php7.2-xml php7.2-zip

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

composer --version

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my_app
```

I set the storage limit to 30gb in the instance. I tried to find a solution and everybody suggested to set the Composer limit to `=-1`. It still didn't resolve my issue.

I got this error when installing packages with Composer:

```
composer updating dependencies (including require-dev) killed
```

I tried to find the memory limit like this:

```
 php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

It showed -1.

I also got this memory information:

[image]

It showed the memory limit as 128M. Is my issue due to this? If yes, then how can I increase the memory?

I just wanted to know that can we install Laravel with Composer on the free tier. I am not understanding everything clearly on this matter or is it any other configuration issue?

Comment: What error are you getting? What's the memory usage while installing composer? (Check top/htop) Try stopping mysql and any other services during composer install. Try installing composer on a local machine and copying the entire project (including vendor) to your server. 512mb of ram is enough to run laravel and mysql for a few users, but you may find this kind of problems while installing

Comment: i got error composer updating dependencies (including require-dev) killed .. cpl of times . and i used  php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"  to check memory limit . it shows -1

Comment: What command do you run? `composer updating dependencies` does not look good, that should not occur when you deploy something to a server

Comment: i updated commands what  used in explanation .please suggest

Comment: Why do you run `create-project` on a servr? Shouldn't that be used on a local development machine?

Comment: It's just taken from few tutorial . I was trying everything to reproduce composer.lock file on server

Comment: @NeerajVerma Please add your own answer with the solution, rather than putting an answer in the Question. This will help future readers understand the situation and the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, we can.**

I verified that on **AWS using t2.micro Ubuntu 18.04 with 30GB** (don't need 30GB, but I used what you have).

For `laravel` installation, the following command was used:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

And also got **memory error**:

```
The following exception is caused by a lack of memory or swap, or not having swap configured
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details

In Process.php line 344:

  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory
```

Based on the message, I added **1GB of swap** by following [these](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04/) steps.

Once the swap was setup, I executed `laravel` installation command again and this time it worked.

I tested newly installed `laravel` by generating its standard `blog` project:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

The command worked:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v7.12.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v7.12.0): Loading from cache
Created project in blog
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 92 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
#
# not shown
#
Package manifest generated successfully.
> @php artisan key:generate --ansi
Application key set successfully.
```

Hope this helps.

p.s. 
Installing `php` and various `php` extensions were also required.

Comment: comprehensive & great answer.

Comment: @Ersoy Thanks. Have you managed to install `laravel`?

Comment: i wasn't the one asking question, but saw the answer.

Comment: @Ersoy I see. My mistake. Sorry and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Rob [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026835/3486675) this previously:

Download an existing `composer.lock` file from your git project. Then install Composer in same location. If you don't have a `composer.lock` file in your git repository, first push it to git from your development environment. Thanks Rob.

Comment: Also, you could add that, if you do not have the `composer.lock` in repository,  the `composer install` can be run in a similar development machine with adequate amount of memory (and commit it to the repository, of course).